# ms-transform vs webkit-transform?

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-transforms

I am new to CSS transform and animation, I was just wondering what is difference between those two.

I under `-webkit-transform` is specific to chrome and `-moz-tranform` is to Mozilla Firefox.
I can't find a difference between -webkit and -ms.

Comment: `-ms` is for Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well `-webkit-` is for Chrome and safari where as `-ms` is for Internet Explorer

there are also other prefixes like  -moz- for Firefox and -o- for Opera

here a link that might help:
http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/

Answer (score 4):

Those are CSS Vendor prefixes, if you google just that, you'll find all the information you need.

Android: -webkit-

Chrome: -webkit-

iOS: -webkit-

Safari: -webkit-

Firefox: -moz-

Internet Explorer: -ms-

As bonus:
Opera: -o-

Answer (score 3):

`-webkit-` prefix for the browser that's using [webkit](http://www.webkit.org/) engine like `safari`,`chrome`.
and `-ms-` for `Microsft IE` versions.
also we have a `-moz-` prefix for old `mozila` version and also `-o-` for opera version.
they called `CSS Vendor Prefixes`

CSS vendor prefixes or CSS browser prefixes are a way for browser makers to add support for new CSS features in a sort of testing and experimentation period. Browser prefixes are used to add new features that may not be part of a formal specification and to implement features in a specification that hasn’t been finalized

here is a [CSS vendor Prefix overview](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/)

also for a ReadMore about that:
[What Are They and Why You Should Use Them](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm)