# css animation doesn't work with internet explorer browser (transform)

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-frontend

I created an css animation (transform & keyframes) to rotate the cube.

However, it does not work with Internet Explorer browser.
I also tried the vendor prefix (-ms-).
But that was not the solution.

It is require by the project requirements, if it is not possible, another solution must be considered.

Is it possible to make this work with Internet Explorer browser?

https://jsfiddle.net/1acjLn53/

HTML

```
<div class="cube">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="side m--1"></div>
    <div class="side m--2"></div>
    <div class="side m--3"></div>
    <div class="side m--4"></div>
    <div class="side m--5"></div>
    <div class="side m--6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cube {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: 126px;
  width: 126px;
}
.container {
  -webkit-animation: rotation 6s infinite;
  animation: rotation 6s infinite;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  height: 56px;
  top: 50px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  width: 56px;
}
.container > div {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  height: 56px;
  width: 56px;
}
.side.m--1 {
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(28px);
  transform: rotatex(90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(28px);
}
.side.m--2 {
  background-color: #aaa;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(28px);
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(28px);
}
.side.m--3 {
  background-color: #888;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(28px);
  transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(28px);
}
.side.m--4 {
  background-color: #aaa;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(28px);
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(28px);
}
.side.m--5 {
  background-color: #888;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(28px);
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(28px);
}
.side.m--6 {
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(28px);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(28px);
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(90deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg) rotateY(270deg) rotateZ(90deg);
    transform: rotateX(270deg) rotateY(270deg) rotateZ(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(90deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg) rotateY(270deg) rotateZ(90deg);
    transform: rotateX(270deg) rotateY(270deg) rotateZ(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: -ms-transform:   => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037384/ms-transform-vs-webkit-transform

Comment: As mentioned above, the vendor prefix has already been tried. But that was not the solution. So it was display like this [ https://www.browserling.com/browse/win/7/ie/11/https%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2F1acjLn53%2F ].

Comment: Check transform-style:preserve-3d;

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/csstransformspreserve3d/  =>  Not Supported in Internet Explorer 11

Comment: @MrJ : Sorry for the lack of explanation. Certainly it does not support, but it will be the same display state that it is displayed by clicking OK.

Comment: @u238 : Thank you for the advice. The problem has become clear. I will check if other implementations are possible for IE.